# How do I display a button at a certain time, then have it disappear again in Actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to make a game that involves hitting keys/clicking buttons at the right time. I want to have the button/indicator hidden until the right time but am having a bit of trouble getting it to display. This is the code I have for it so far.

```
var count:Number = 5;
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000, count);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);
myTimer.start();
function countdown(event:TimerEvent): void {
    timer_txt.text = String((count)-myTimer.currentCount);
}

btnthing.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnclick);

btnthing.visible=false;

while (((count)-myTimer.currentCount)==1) {
    btnthing.visible=true;
}

function btnclick(e:MouseEvent): void {
    if (((count)-myTimer.currentCount) == 1) {
        myTimer.stop();
        btnthing.visible=false;
        time_txt.text = "Yay!";
    } else {
        myTimer.stop();
        gotoAndStop(3);
    }
}
```

So far my code starts the timer and displays a countdown. If I remove the part that hides/shows the button, everything works fine.

```
var count:Number = 5;
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000, count);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);
myTimer.start();
function countdown(event:TimerEvent): void {
    timer_txt.text = String((count)-myTimer.currentCount);
}

btnthing.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnclick);

function btnclick(e:MouseEvent): void {
    if (((count)-myTimer.currentCount) == 1) {
        myTimer.stop();
        btnthing.visible=false;
        timer_txt.text = "Yay!";
    } else {
        myTimer.stop();
        gotoAndStop(3);
    }
}
```

If anyone could help me get this right that would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the 'while' loop correctly. Change it to a 'if' statement and put it inside the countdown function like this:

```
function countdown(event:TimerEvent): void 
{
    timer_txt.text = String((count)-myTimer.currentCount);

    if (((count)-myTimer.currentCount)==1) {
      btnthing.visible=true;
    }
}
```

so that your code tests for the currentCount on each tick of the timer and finally does something about it. 
Read up on 'while' loops - they don't do exactly what you think they do and it's easy to get 'em into infinite repitions if you don't increment the thing that you're changing within the loop.

Comment: You're a legend mate. Thanks!